# Scraping cached pages

Tags: python, scrapy, browser-cache

I'm using `scrapy` in order to fetch some web content, in this fashion:

```
class PitchforkTracks(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pitchfork_tracks"
    allowed_domains = ["pitchfork.com"]
    start_urls = [
                    "http://pitchfork.com/reviews/best/tracks/?page=1",
                    "http://pitchfork.com/reviews/best/tracks/?page=2",
                    "http://pitchfork.com/reviews/best/tracks/?page=3",
     ]
```

everything is working fine.

now, instead of hitting the pages directely, I would like to scrape `google` `caches` of the same pages.

what is the proper `syntax`to achieve that?

**PS:** I have tried `"cache:http://pitchfork.com/reviews/best/tracks/?page=1",`, to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use following Google URL for scraping cache page

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://pitchfork.com/reviews/best/tracks/?page=1

Comment: does webcache.googleusercontent.com block bots ?